# How do I create a scope that traverses a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, named-scope

I have these models (psuedocode):

```
class Order
    has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem
    belongs_to :purchasable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :order
end

class Tile
    has_one :line_item, :as => :purchasable
end
```

I want to make a scope that allows me to access tiles from an order. something like `Order#tiles` so that I can do things like this in controllers:

```
my_order.tiles.new(...)
my_order.tiles.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(...)
```

How can I construct such a scope? (or is there another technique I should use?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associations you have don't work together.  I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :tiles, :through => :line_items, :source => :purchasable, :source_type => "Tile"
  ...
end

class LineItem
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :purchasable, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end

class Tile
  has_many :line_items, :as => :purchasable
  ...
end
```

Comment: I've modified them slightly to reflect my actual code. I had a couple mistakes. Based on my revision do you know how to create the desired scope?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the line `has_many :tiles, :through => :line_items, :source => :purchasable, :source_type => "Tile"` from my answer.  It will allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Oh, great! I didn't realize it was that simple.

Comment: The line of code is fairly simple, but the concepts behind it are more advanced.  Quite honestly, you don't come across an association like that very often, so you had a very good question.  +1